# How to denote the size of a list?

Tags: notation

Suppose I have a list (not a set) with entries $[x, x, x, y, z]$. Then the list is size of $5$.

What is the mathematical function that returns the number of elements?

Does cardinality only work on sets?

Comment: I think that [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) may help you.

Comment: If the list is unordered, such an object is sometimes called a *multiset*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset . One could also call it, well, an *unordered list*, though this sounds like something a computer scientist might be more likely to say than a mathematician. If the order does matter, we usually write $(x, x, x, y, z)$ rather than with braces, and call the object a *finite sequence* or *ordered list*. In the ordered case, probably the most common term is *length*. I know of no special term for the unordered case, though probably most people would understand *length* here too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We usually write ordered lists with parentheses, e.g. $(x,x,x,y,z)$. It would be entirely clear what you mean if you said $|(x,x,x,y,z)|=5$, though if you were trying to be excruciatingly pedantic, you might want to introduce a length function $\mathrm{len}((x,x,x,y,z))$ = 5.